# Is a question about the architecture of an external GitHub demo project on topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I was reading a blog post from Jason Taylor, about building and architecture with his "Northwind Traders" project.

And I had a question about one particular block of code, a class/factory thing he used around the DbContext.

I don't know if questions asking about the use of a class in an external project are a good fit on Stack Overflow. I can make it match the on topics checklist quite easily, but still.

I'm talking about this project:  https://github.com/JasonGT/NorthwindTraders

Comment: Can you formulate a reasonably short, ***self-contained*** question around this which does not require anyone to read the entire project source code on Github, and the question would be otherwise on-topic?

Comment: @deceze, in my hypotetique SO question or in this meta so people can judge? I mean you want me to sandbox the question here, I can do that ??

Comment: It was meant as a rough guide to the answer to this question. Questions talk about external projects all the time in some way or another; the important point is that the question must be self-contained and otherwise be on-topic.

Comment: I suppose this depends on what you also mean by "architecture".  Could you be a bit more specific/narrow in this Meta question so we could give you a more accurate answer?

Answer (score -4):

If a question is "I am studying this code and I do not understand why.. " then I would skip it unless:

- it can be formulated to become interesting for other developers (then SO/SE)
- it can be formulated to become interesting for contributors (then GitHub)
- or for me (then prototyping alternatives by myself).

Comment: "Interest" is not a measure of topicality.

Comment: I know, I know. Some people think that SO "measured values" including "measure of topicality" are given directly like physics laws and there are no any human idea behind. "It is just a table defined function".